# What is the best library to find a white line on the floor? C/Java

Tags: java, android, c, ios, microcontroller

What is the best library (in C, Java, ...) to find a white line on the floor?

By "find a white line" I mean to analyse some images in real-time from a webcam (from a smartphone, extern webcam), do some image processing and get a direction for a robot (through a microcontroler).

Is it possible to program on a smartphone (Android, ios) or a micro controller? (if not, on a computer through a WiFi connection)

Comment: Serach for "computer vision java". Maybe this Q helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501811/what-is-the-best-open-source-pure-java-computer-vision-library

Comment: FWIW, every keyword in your question does not need to be a tag, and it really hinders readability.

Comment: Do not drink too much ... ;->

Answer (score 2):

With Android you can use OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision Library), there is a lot of examples and howto's in this website :

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android

It is really step by step.