# Java: how to search and match a region of image part of a larger image?

Tags: java, computer-vision

what java library exists that allows me to search for a given region of a picture? For example, I want to search for a specific picture within a larger picture.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider taking a look at [imagej](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/concepts.html) for a library to process the image. [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501811/what-is-the-best-open-source-pure-java-computer-vision-library) also has some good links as to other libraries you could use.

For tackling the actual problem of searching an image part in a larger image, I urge you to look at several resources: [a thesis on region based image similarity search](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.103.1099&rep=rep1&type=pdf), [cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis), and [another article on efficient region-based image retrieval](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.91.1369&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

I was unable to find a Java library that already fills this void, so you may have to roll your own.